# Django rest-framework - set_password on instance in update function returns 'None'

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm trying to update the password of a django user with the ModelSerializer of the django rest-framework. Using set_password inside the create method works without any problem. But whenever I call set_password on the instance within the update mehod, it returns 'None' .

```
class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = super().create(validated_data)
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        
        if validated_data.get('password'):
            instance.password = instance.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Even setting a static password returns 'None':

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.password = instance.set_password('secret')
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

But I have no glue, why this happens.
Django version is 4.1.2, djangorestframework 3.14.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it clearly states in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password) that user.set_password takes care of hashing the password and setting it on user instance, it just does not save the instance in the database.
so instead of

```
instance.password = instance.set_password('secret')
instance.save()
```

you should be doing

```
instance.set_password('secret')
instance.save()
```

similar to what you did in `def create(self, validated_data)`

Comment: Hi Muhammad, yes, you're right. I completely missed that.